# Rails with react, react-router gems fails to precompile when pushing to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `resolve' for nil:NilClass
remote:        /tmp/build_c973337fb25108cb9d5546369a8b22b0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/react-router-rails-0.13.3.2/lib/react/router/rails/railtie.rb:11:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c973337fb25108cb9d5546369a8b22b0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/react-router-rails-0.13.3.2/lib/react/router/renderer.rb:78:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_c973337fb25108cb9d5546369a8b22b0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/react-router-rails-0.13.3.2/lib/react/router/renderer.rb:78:in `setup_combined_js'
remote:

...

remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: I'm seeing this same thing.  Did you ever get this worked out?